# Azure DevOps 'Custom comment' and 'Import existing resources' explanation

Tags: azure-devops

Can someone provide an explanation of how Custom Comment and 'Import Existing Resources' are used when setting up a Git/Azure repository in ADO?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a blog posted by "Try Catch Debug" which provides an explanation for that, hope that helps:

[Custom Comment Import Existing Resources in Azure DevOps: ADO Git/Azure Repository Setting Explanation](https://trycatchdebug.net/news/1133898/azure-devops-custom-comment-import)

> **What is Custom Comment Import?**
>
> Custom Comment Import is a feature in Azure DevOps that allows you to
> import comments from an external source and associate them with a work
> item. This can be useful when you have existing comments or
> discussions in another system that you want to bring into Azure
> DevOps. In this article, we will focus on using this feature with a
> Git/Azure Repository.
>
> **Setting up Custom Comment Import with a Git/Azure Repository** To use Custom Comment Import with a Git/Azure Repository, you will need
> to set up a few things in Azure DevOps. Here are the steps:
>
> 1. Navigate to the Boards section of Azure DevOps and select the
>    project you want to work with.
> 2. Select the work item you want to associate the comments with.
> 3. Click on the "..." menu in the upper right corner of the work item
>    and select "Import comments".
> 4. In the Import comments dialog, select "Git/Azure Repository" as the
>    source.
> 5. Enter the URL of the Git/Azure Repository and the branch or commit
>    hash you want to import comments from.
> 6. Select the options you want for importing the comments, such as
>    whether to include deleted comments or comments from merged
>    branches.
> 7. Click "Import" to start the import process.
>
> Code Block Example:
> Here is an example of what the Import comments
> dialog might look like:
>
> ```
> python
> import requests
>
> url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/comments?api-version=6.0"
> headers = {
>     "Authorization": "Bearer {token}",
>     "Content-Type": "application/json"
> }
>
> data = {
>     "comments": [
>         {
>             "text": "This is a comment imported from a Git/Azure Repository.",
>             "createdDate": "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z"
>         }
>     ]
> }
>
> response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
> ```
>
> **Key Concepts** Here are some key concepts to keep in mind when using Custom Comment Import with a Git/Azure Repository:
>
> - You can import comments from any Git/Azure Repository, not just those    hosted in Azure DevOps.
> - You can import comments from a specific branch or commit hash, or    from all branches in a repository.
> - You can choose to include or exclude deleted comments and comments    from merged branches.
> - Imported comments are associated with the work item in Azure DevOps,    but are not editable in Azure DevOps.
> - Imported comments are displayed in the "Comments" tab of the work    item in Azure DevOps.
>
> Custom Comment Import is a useful feature in Azure DevOps that allows
> you to import comments from an external source and associate them with
> a work item. When using this feature with a Git/Azure Repository, you
> can import comments from any Git/Azure Repository, not just those
> hosted in Azure DevOps. You can import comments from a specific branch
> or commit hash, or from all branches in a repository. You can choose
> to include or exclude deleted comments and comments from merged
> branches. Imported comments are associated with the work item in Azure
> DevOps, but are not editable in Azure DevOps. They are displayed in
> the "Comments" tab of the work item in Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 1):

The context "Azure DevOps" is not properly correct. You can see this flag in **Azure Synapse Analytics** and **Azure Data Factory** (ADF) when you configure the Git integration with **Azure DevOps** or **GitHub**.

- **Custom comment**: when this box is selected, you can customize the comment to your commits (when you click the Commit All button in Synapse/ADF Studio).
- **Import existing resources**: when this box is selected, the existing resources are imported from the Synapse/ADF Studio into the associated Git repository in JSON format.

*Reference*:

- [Source control in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/source-control)
- [Source control in Synapse Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/source-control)